# How to convert a smooth shape into a convex polygon using python?

Tags: python, algorithm, opencv, computer-vision

[image: Example of the problem]

Given a smooth contour, I want to approximate a regular convex polygon from it. The number of vertices in the polygon could be a parameter which we can pass.

I am absolutely lost on this. I would appreciate any literature, resource, approach you have.

https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html#gsc.tab=0

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
im = cv.imread('test.jpg')
imgray = cv.cvtColor(im, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, thresh = cv.threshold(imgray, 127, 255, 0)
contours, hierarchy = cv.findContours(thresh, cv.RETR_TREE, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

All i have found is this resource

Comment: I wrote about *the* algorithm to compute the convex hull of a polygon on my blog here: https://www.crisluengo.net/archives/405/ -- I used MATLAB code to illustrate how it works, you'd have to translate to Python; though I'm sure there already are implementations in Python as well.

Comment: In the picture you've shown, the polygons are **not** convex and certainly **not** regular.

Comment: Apologies @Stef, I wasn't even able to provide a better reference image.

Comment: @mach-12 Are you sure that you want the polygon to be regular and convex? Do you know what these two words mean for a polygon?

Comment: you haven't encountered `cv.approxPolyDP` yet. it's not the only solution. there are others that give better results.